# Binary Search with user interaction & random list generation with timestamp

Tags: python-3.x

So I have been having problems with my code it is still a work in progress as I have not added a timestamp to time the searches but I keep getting an error that my variable is not defined. I have tried to correct and fix my indents and even try to insert different indents. not the issue. The project was to generate a list of 10,000 numbers and binary search for a specific number of the users choice with timestamps before and after the search. HELP?!

```
from random import *
def bisection():
   n=input("Please type the number here we are searching for:")
   my_randoms=[]
   for i in range(10):
       my_randoms.append(randrange(1,10001,1))
   s=my_randoms
   g=0
   low=0
   high=len(s)-1
   ans=(high+low)/2
   g+=1
   while s[ans]!=n:
      if  s[ans]<n:
          low=ans+1
      else:
          high=ans
          ans=(high+low)/2
          g+=1
   print ("iterations = ",str(g))
bisection()
```

Comment: When the "if" statement is true, "ans" is not changed so you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Sorry Maybe I am just thick how does that fix the problem of defining (g)? Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: I cut and paste your code and it runs forever - `no compiler errors though`.